# Lumber: Command 'lumber' not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu, npm, forestadmin

I just setup a **Rails Application** in my **Ubuntu 18** machine, and I want to connect it to [Forest Admin](https://forestadmin.com). However, Forest Admin requires that I set up a **Node Application** using npm first. The node application requires the installation of [Lumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lumber-cli) CLI tool in order to install Forest Admin.

I have however installed [Lumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lumber-cli) CLI tool by running the command below:

```
npm install -g lumber-cli@latest -s
```

When I run the command below `npm lumber -version` in my command line terminal, I get the response:

```
6.13.4
```

But when I try to generate the Forest Admin using the command below:

```
lumber generate "my_project"...
```

I get the following error:

> Command 'lumber' not found

I need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it:**

The issue is because NPM does not have the **write access** to the directory that will contain the package you want to install (here `lumber-cli`).

To solve this issue, override the default directory where your global NPM packages will be stored:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Then, configure NPM to use this directory instead of the default one:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

Then, make the node executables accessible from your `PATH`. To do so, export the environment variable `PATH` by opening or creating the file `~/.profile` and add this line at the end:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Finally, reload the `~/.profile` file:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Try installing `lumber cli` again using the command below:

```
npm install -g lumber-cli@latest -s
```

It should be able to install lumber without any error, and also display the directory where `lumber-cli` is installed.

**Reference:** [Prevent permission errors at installation](https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/how-tos/prevent-permission-errors-at-installation)

**That's all**

**I hope this helps**

Comment: I am having same issue in windows